# Maven and Apache Sling - No plugin found

Tags: java, apache, maven, sling

Complete newb to maven, sling and java in general so I apologize in advance.  I've got maven up and running and am trying to get it running with apache sling.  But when I try to start up sling using "mvn launchpad:run" I'm running into the following error:

[ERROR] no plugin found for prefix 'launchpad' in the current project and in the plugin     groups[org.apache.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (MYLOCALPATH), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2]

Any help is greatly appreciated or if I could just get pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on Apache Sling, but based on the error message, it looks like you did not define the maven-launchpad-plugin in your pom.xml like below

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-launchpad-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'm really unfamiliar with the concepts of Sling but were exactly do you put the POM file? I'm familiar with creating one just don't know were to put it.

Comment: pom.xml should be at the root directory of your project. You execute the mvn launchpad:run at the same directory. This is a concept about  Maven rather than Sling.